# Create a map from an Iterable<Map.Entry> in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, collections

I need to fill map with `Iterable<Map.Entry>`. The following is an original java code:

```
Iterable<Map.Entry<String, String>> conf;
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> itr = conf.iterator();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String, String> kv = itr.next();
    map.put(kv.getKey(), kv.getValue());
}
```

I have to rewrite it in groovy. Is there a concise groovy-way to do it?

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as solution if you think it answers your question so others know it's answered, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [`collectEntries`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#collectEntries(groovy.lang.Closure)) for that. It's similar to `collect`, but it's purpose is to create a `Map`.

```
def sourceMap = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]
Iterable<Map.Entry<String, String>> conf = sourceMap.entrySet()

def map = conf.collectEntries {
    [(it.key): it.value]
}
```

Note the round braces around `it.key` that allow you to use a variable reference as key of the newly generated `Entry`.

Answer (score 1):

In Groovy you can use the **each closure** instead of **Iterator** as follows

```
Map<Map.Entry<String, String>> sourceMap = ["key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2"]
Map<Map.Entry<String, String>> targetMap = [:]
sourceMap.each{ key, value ->
targetMap[key] = value
}

println ​targetMap
```

Working example here : https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5100319096700928